# How can I block specific ajax call by its url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to block an ajax call by its url from another script/js file? I want something like that..

```
if(ajax_url == 'if_URL_match_then_block_this_ajax_call'){
   //block lower ajax call
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'if_URL_match_then_block_this_ajax_call',
    data: {},
    success: function(e) {
      //some event after success...
    }
});
```

Comment: Add an else block? Or use `ajax_url !== 'if_URL_match_then_block_this_ajax_call'`?

Comment: Use if else case here if it's matched with url call ajax method else return

Comment: want it from another function/script/js file

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell by the code snippet, but if this code is inside a function you could exit the function early if you detected the URL you didn't want to send a request for.

```js
function get(url) {
  if(url === '/some/url/to/block'){
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url,
    data: {},
    success: function(e) {
      //some event after success...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you add to what OP mentions in the question, apart from a wrapper function?

Comment: I forgot the part that actually answered the question. ‍♂️ Thanks for commenting. I added in the return statement.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Actually I want to block from another script.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found an answer. I can block a specific url when ajax call start sending request.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
  if(options.url == 'if_URL_match_then_block_this_ajax_call'){
    console.log('ajax call abort');
    console.log(event, xhr, options);
    xhr.abort();
  }
});
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/